# Which is generally faster to test for zero in x86 ASM: "TEST EAX, EAX" versus "TEST AL, AL"?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, micro-optimization

Which is generally faster to test the byte in AL for zero / non-zero?

- `TEST EAX, EAX`
- `TEST AL, AL`

Assume a previous `"MOVZX EAX, BYTE PTR [ESP+4]"` instruction loaded a byte parameter with zero-extension to the remainder of EAX, preventing the combine-value penalty that I already know about.

So AL=EAX and there are no partial-register penalties for reading EAX.

Intuitively just examining AL might let you think it's faster, but I'm betting there are more penalty issues to consider for byte access of a >32-bit register.

Any info/details appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You mean `movzx eax, [esp+4]`. Examining `eax` or `al` makes no speed difference. Note you could also `test byte [esp+4], 0xff`

Comment: Oops, yes, corrected/edited! Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the difference in performance, **if any**, would be impossible to measure, as it'll drown in the noise. And definitely irrelevant to anything user visible.

Comment: You would have a stall if you wrote `al` and read `eax`, but only on pre SandyBridge CPUs. Using `movzx` is the real trick here.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: If there was a difference, we could design a microbenchmark to measure it at least via performance counters.  You can put `test` in a data dependency chain with `setcc` or `cmovcc`, instead of `jcc`, to verify that it still has 1 cycle latency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code-size is equal, and so is performance on all x86 CPUs AFAIK.**

Intel CPUs (with partial-register renaming) definitely don't have a penalty for reading AL after writing EAX.  Other CPUs also have no penalty for reading low-byte registers.

Reading AH would have a penalty on Intel CPUs, like some extra latency.  ([How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to))

In general 32-bit operand-size and 8-bit operand size (with low-8 not high-8) are equal speed except for the false-dependencies or later partial-register reading penalties of *writing* an 8-bit register.  Since TEST only reads registers, this can't be a problem.  Even `add al, bl` is fine: the instruction already had an input dependency on both registers, and on Sandybridge-family a RMW to the low byte of a register doesn't rename it separately.  (Haswell and later don't rename low-byte registers separately anyway).

Pick whichever operand-size you like.  8-bit and 32-bit are basically equal.  The choice is just a matter of human readability.  If you're going to work with the value as a 32-bit integer later, then go 32-bit.  If it's logically still an 8-bit value and you were only using `movzx` as the x86 equivalent of ARM `ldrb` or MIPS `lbu`, then using 8-bit makes sense.

There are code-size advantages to instructions like `cmp al, imm` which can use the no-modrm short-form encoding.  `cmp al, 0` is still worse than `test al,al` on *some* old CPUs (Core 2), where cmp/jcc macro-fusion is less flexible than test/jcc macro-fusion.  ([Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806))

---

There is one difference between these instructions: `test al,al` sets **SF** according to the high bit of AL (which can be non-zero).  `test eax,eax` will always clear SF.  If you only care about ZF then that makes no difference, but if you have a use for the high bit in SF for a later branch or cmovcc/setcc then you can avoid doing a 2nd `test`.

---

#### Other ways to test a byte in memory:

If you're consuming the flag result with setcc or cmovcc, not a jcc branch, then macro-fusion doesn't matter in the discussion below.

**If you also need the actual value in a register later, `movzx`/`test`/`jcc` is almost certainly best**.  Otherwise you can consider a memory-destination compare.

`cmp [mem], immediate` can micro-fuse into a load+cmp uop on Intel, as long as the addressing mode is not RIP-relative.  (On Sandybridge-family, indexed addressing modes will un-laminate even on Haswell and later:  See [Micro fusion and addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes)).  Agner Fog doesn't mention whether AMD has this limitation for fusing cmp/jcc with a memory operand.

```
;;; no downside for setcc or cmovcc, only with JCC on Intel
;;; unknown on AMD
    cmp byte [esp+4], 0       ; micro-fuses into load+cmp with this addressing mode
    jnz   ...                 ; breaks macro-fusion on SnB-family
```

I don't have an AMD CPU to test whether Ryzen or any other AMD still fuses cmp/jcc when the cmp is `mem, immediate`.  Modern AMD CPUs *do* in general do cmp/jcc and test/jcc fusion.  (But not add/sub/and/jcc fusion like SnB-family).

**`cmp mem,imm` / `jcc`**   (vs. `movzx`/`test+jcc`):

- smaller code-size in bytes
- same number of front-end / fused-domain uops (2) on mainstream Intel.  This would be 3 front-end uops if micro-fusion of the `cmp`+load wasn't possible, e.g. with a RIP-relative addressing mode + immediate.  Or on Sandybridge-family with an indexed addressing mode, it would unlaminate to 3 uops after decode but before issuing into the back-end.

  Advantage: this is still 2 on Silvermont/Goldmont / KNL or very old CPUs without macro-fusion.  The main advantage of movzx/test/jcc over this is macro-fusion, so it falls behind on CPUs where that doesn't happen.
- 3 back-end uops (unfused domain = execution ports and space in the scheduler aka RS) because `cmp`-immediate can't macro-fuse with a JCC on Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs (tested on Skylake). The uops are load, cmp, and a separate branch uop.  (vs. 2 for `movzx` / `test+jcc`).  Back-end uops usually aren't a bottleneck directly, but if the load isn't ready for a while it takes up more space in the RS, limiting how much further past this out-of-order execution can see.

**`cmp [mem], reg`  / `jcc` *can* macro + micro-fuse into a single compare+branch uop so it's excellent**.  If you need a zeroed register for anything later in your function, do xor-zero it first and use it for a single-uop compare+branch on memory.

```
    movzx  eax, [esp+4]       ; 1 uop (load-port only on Intel and Ryzen)
    test   al,al                     ; fuses with jcc
    jnz    ...                ; 1 uop
```

This is still 2 uops for the front-end but only 2 for the back-end as well.  The test/jcc macro-fuse together.  It costs more code-size, though.

If you aren't branching but instead using the FLAGS result for `cmovcc` or `setcc`, using `cmp mem, imm` has no downside.  It can micro-fuse as long as you don't use a RIP-relative addressing mode (which always blocks micro-fusion when there's also an immediate), or an indexed addressing mode.

Comment: "Agner Fog doesn't mention this limitation for AMD has this limitation and cmp with a memory operand" There's something dodgy about this sentence. It doesn't read well.

Comment: @SepRoland: thanks, fixed.  I must have changed my mind about what to say mid-sentence, and got out of sync with my fingers.

Comment: Related: [What is instruction fusion in contemporary x86 processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56413517) has some of the same fusion test results