# Is there a better way to any detect bits that are set in a 16-byte array of flags?

Tags: c++, x86-64, simd, sse, micro-optimization

```
    ALIGNTO(16) uint8_t noise_frame_flags[16] = { 0 };

    // Code detects noise and sets noise_frame_flags omitted

    __m128i xmm0            = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)noise_frame_flags);
    bool    isNoiseToCancel = _mm_extract_epi64(xmm0, 0) | _mm_extract_epi64(xmm0, 1);

    if (isNoiseToCancel)
        cancelNoises(audiobuffer, nAudioChannels, audio_samples, noise_frame_flags);
```

This is a code snippet from my AV Capture tool on Linux. noise_frame_flags here is an array of flags for 16-channel audio. For each channel, the corresponding byte can be either 0 or 1. 1 is indicating that the channel has some noise to cancel. For example, if noise_frame_flags[0] == 1, that means first channel noise flag is set (by the omitted code).

Even if a single "flag" is set then I need to call `cancelNoises`. And this code seems to work fine in that matter. As you see I used `_mm_load_si128` to load a whole array of flags that is correctly aligned and then two `_mm_extract_epi64` to extract "flags". My question is there a better way to do this (using pop count maybe)?

Note: `ALIGNTO(16)` is a macro expands to correct GCC equivalent but nicer looking.

Comment: [std::popcount from C++ 20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount).

Comment: I use GCC (g++) 8.4.0 and my concern is performance.

Comment: Well, the performance part should be taken care of by the implementers of `popcount`.  They are not going to write half-baked solutions.

Comment: Ok but, I think I'm stuck with the C++11 standard for a while. You mentioned C++ 20. Can I still use it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: How do you propose using `std::popcount` on a `uint8_t [16]` anyway?  Even if it was possible, that wrapper doesn't solve the strict-aliasing problem any more than `_popcnt64` or `_mm_popcnt_u64` (which we know are available because the code is using other intrinsics from `immintrin.h`), and it's not obvious what you'd do with 16 bytes of data to make popcnt useful.

Comment: @thekamilz: Updated my answer to save a uop.  `add rax, [mem]` can macro-fuse with a JCC, with some addressing modes.

Comment: Ok, I'll think I'll update the code again. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered replacing the array `noise_frame_flags` with a `uint16_t` bitmask?  Then the test is trivial.

Comment: Yes, and I didn't want to fiddle with the bits in both functions. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you eventually want a 64-bit OR to look for any non-zero bits in either half, but it's not efficient to get those `uint64_t` values from a 128-bit load and then extract.

In asm you just want a `mov` load and a memory-source `or` or `add`, which will set ZF just like you're doing now.  Two loads from the same cache line are very cheap; current CPUs have at least 2/clock load throughput.  The extra ALU work to extract from a single 128-bit load is just not worth it, even if you did shuffle / `por` to set up for a single `movq`.

In C++, use `memcpy` to do strict-aliasing safe loads of `uint64_t` tmp vars, then `if(a | b)`.  This is still SIMD, just [SWAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR) (SIMD Within A Register).

**`add` is even better than `or`: it can [macro-fuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771526/x86-64-assembly-loop-conditions-and-out-of-order)** with most `jcc` instructions on Intel Sandybridge-family (but not AMD).  `or` can't fuse with branch instructions on any CPUs.  Since your values are `0` or `1`, we can't have a case of two non-zero values adding to produce a zero, which is why you'd normally use `or` for the general case.

(Some addressing modes may defeat micro or macro-fusion on Intel.  Or maybe it always works since there's no immediate involved. It really is possible for `add rax, [mem]` / `jnz` to go through the front-end and ROB as a single uop, and execute in the back-end as only 2 (load + add/sub-and-branch).  Assuming it's about the same as [`cmp` on my Skylake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413517/what-is-instruction-fusion-in-contemporary-x86-processors/56413946#56413946), except it does write the destination so Haswell and later can maybe keep it micro-fused even for indexed addressing modes.)

```
    uint64_t a, b;
    memcpy(&a, noise_frame_flags+0, sizeof(a));   // strict-aliasing-safe loads
    memcpy(&b, noise_frame_flags+8, sizeof(b));   // which optimize to MOV qword
    bool  isNoiseToCancel = a + b;   // equivalent to a | b  for bool inputs
```

This should compile to 3 asm instructions which will decode to 2 uops total, or 3 on AMD CPUs where JCC can only fuse with `cmp` or `test`.

`union { alignas(16) uint8_t flags[16]; uint64_t chunks[2];};` would be safe in C99, but not ISO C++.  Most but not all C++ compilers that support Intel intrinsics define the behaviour of union type-punning.  (I think @jww has said SunCC doesn't.)

In C++11, you don't need a custom macro for `ALIGNTO(16)`, just use `alignas(16)`.  Also supported in C11 if you `#include <stdalign.h>`

---

#### Alternatives:

`movdqa` 16-byte load / SSE4.1 `ptest xmm0, xmm0` / `jnz` - 4 uops on Intel CPUs, 3 on AMD.
Intel runs `ptest` as 2 uops, and it can't macro-fuse with `jcc`.
AMD CPUs run `ptest` as 1 uop, but it still can't fuse.
If you had an all-ones or all-zeros constant in a register, `ptest xmm0, [mem]` would work to save a uop on Intel (depending on addressing mode), but that's still 3 total.

**PTEST is only good for checking a 32-byte array with AVX1 or AVX2**.  (Surprisingly, [`vptest ymm` only requires AVX1](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptest)).  Then it's about break-even with AVX2 `vmovdqa` / `vpslld ymm0, 7` / `vpmovmskb eax,ymm0` / `test+jnz`.  See TrentP's answer for portable GNU C native vector source code that should compile to `vptest` on x86 with AVX available, and maybe to something clunky on other ISAs like ARM depending on how good their horizontal OR support is.

---

`popcnt` wouldn't be useful unless you want to break down the work depending on how many bits are set.
In that case, yes, sure, you can turn the bool array into a bitmap that you can scan easily, probably more efficient than `_mm_sad_epu8` against a zeroed register to sum into two 8-byte halves.

```
   __m128i vflags = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)noise_frame_flags);
   vflags = _mm_slli_epi32(vflags, 7);
   unsigned flagmask = _mm_movemask_epi8(vflags);
   if (flagmask) {
       unsigned flagcount = __builtin_popcount(flagmask);  // popcnt with -march=nehalem or higher
       unsigned first_setflag = __builtin_ctz(flagmask);   // tzcnt if available, else BSF
       vflags &= vflags - 1;   // clear lowest set bit.  blsr if compiled with -march=haswell or bdver2 or newer.
      ...
   }
```

(Don't actually use `-march=bdver2` or `-march=nehalem`, unless you want to set an ISA baseline but also use `-mtune=haswell` or something more modern.  There are individual options like `-mpopcnt` and `-mbmi`, but generally good to enable all ISA extensions that some CPU supports, so you don't miss out on useful stuff the compiler can use.)

Comment: N.B.: `ptest xmm0, [mem]` also works with an all-zero register, if you check `CF` instead of `ZF` (I assume there is no other advantage, though).

Comment: @chtz: Oh right, yeah.  Saves a back-end uop on Intel, but not a front-end uop.  (xor-zeroing is as cheap as a NOP on Intel, but on AMD it and the all-ones idiom both need a back-end uop to write zeros or ones to a vector.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with for doing this:

```
#define VLEN 8
typedef int vNb __attribute__((vector_size(VLEN*sizeof(int))));

// Constants for 128 or 256 bit registers
#if VLEN == 8
#define V(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
#else
#define V(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) a,b,c,d
#endif
#define SWAP128 V(4,5,6,7, 0,1,2,3)
#define SWAP64 V(2,3, 0,1,  6,7, 4,5)
#define SWAP32 V(1, 0,  3, 2,  5, 4,  7, 6)

static bool any(vNb x) {
    if (VLEN >= 8)
        x |= __builtin_shufflevector(x,x, SWAP128);
    x |= __builtin_shufflevector(x,x, SWAP64);
    x |= __builtin_shufflevector(x,x, SWAP32);
    return x[0];
}
```

With `VLEN` = 8, this will use 256-bit registers if the arch supports it.  Change to 4 to use 128 bit.

This should compile to a single `vptest` instruction.

Comment: Good idea if SSE4.1 is available, but PTEST is 2 uops on mainstream Intel CPUs (1 on Zen, or E-cores of Alder Lake though).  So  `movdqa` / `ptest xmm0,xmm0` / `jcc` is 4 (or 3) uops total.  vs. 3 uops on all modern CPUs for `mov rax, [mem]` / `or rax, [mem+4]` / `jcc`.  (Or 4 on Sandybridge or IvyBridge with an indexed addressing mode so the OR unlaminates).  Also larger machine-code size.  In both cases the OR doesn't macro-fuse with the JCC.  Hmm, actually `add` can macro-fuse, and can't overflow, so that's actually more efficient... I'll update my answer.

Comment: This idea is good for a 32-byte vector, though; then `vptest ymm,ymm` is efficient and only requires AVX1, vs. `vmovdqa` load / `vpslld ymm0, 7` / `vpmovmskb` / fused `test+jcc` (also 4 uops including the separate load; unfortunately only AVX-512 can use a memory source vector for shift-immediate).  BTW, `vptest ymm0, [mem]` could work with an all-ones constant in YMM0, but that only helps if doing it in a loop.  If you have to pay for the `vpcmpeqd ymm0,ymm0,ymm0` for every test, it's break-even for the front-end and more back-end uops.