# Is there a mask-and-compare instruction for the x86_64 architecture?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, dynamic-typing

Implementations of programming languages that need to preserve type information at runtime often use some bits of an integer value as tagging bits. A typical expression in the C programming language dealing with such tags looks like:

```
(val && MASK) == TAG
```

In machine language, such a test has to be implemented, for example, as follows:

```
movq val,%rax
andq MASK,%rax
cmpq TAG,%rax
```

In other words, a scratch register is needed if the original value needs to be preserved. As this is typical code to implement type safety in a dynamically typed language and needs to be efficient, I wonder whether there is a single mask-and-compare instruction in the x86_64 ISA. Or is there actually such an instruction in one of the newer extensions of the AMD64 platform I don't know of?

Comment: Depending on what the tag is, you can often get away with `TEST` to check individual bits in the mask.  If the tag is 8 bits, you may be able to use a byte-compare on the least significant bit.  But apart from that, yeah, you're going to have to mask our and then compare.  I don't know any architecture that has a dedicated instruction for the operation you envision.

Comment: @fuz cmp can [macro-fuse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56413517/995714) and [`mov` is "free"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44169342/995714) so the actual cost is low

Comment: @phuclv If it's unclear: `cmp` can macro-fuse with a following conditional branch (not shown in OP's post).  It cannot fuse with `and` on any µarch I know.  That said, `mov` is usually a rename, but a few µarches are affected by errata, the fixes for which disable move elimination, so watch out for that.

Comment: The following instruction will likely be a conditional branch or a conditional move.  Even if the `mov` is just a rename, one register will be clobbered.

Comment: That said, there's no technical reason why such an instruction couldn't exist.  It would likely be very simple to add one if so desired.  However, without microarchitectural changes, it might not be faster than the alternative you propose: execution ports often only support two inputs, so a three-input operation would have to be cracked into two µops.  But once again, that's speculation and not a hard and fast reason for why the instruction you seek does not exist.

Comment: Encoding this as an instruction with 2 register operands and 1 immediate operand has been theoretically possible for ages, but just hasn't been done. A version with 3 register operands would be possible these days. As of Haswell, there is (some) direct support for 3-input µops, and Skylake improved that (you can see this in the improvements to `cmov` for example)

Comment: @fuz If you think it helps, I can rephrase the question from "Why is there..." to "Is there...". In any case, at least concerning subquestions, I believe that more than speculative answers can be given.  For example, there is the question of the encodability of such an instruction and the question if newer architecture actually support the construct directly.

Comment: @Marc Feel free to reword. Is there: as far as I know, not.  Can it be encoded?  Sure, no problem there.  There's multiple ways it could be done both for immediate masks and for register masks.  Special cases that are covered?  If the tag is the low 8, 16, or 32 bits of the datum, you could use byte, word, or dword instructions to compare it.  If the tag is well-designed, you could use the `test` instruction to test individual bits in it (e.g. if ithe tag is the most significant bit plus one other bit, you can use one `test` to distinguish three of the four possible cases in one step).

Comment: APX (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/advanced-performance-extensions-apx.html) will provide a non-destructive AND (into a different register with an EVEX prefix) that avoids the `mov`.  The `mov` doesn't need a back-end execution unit in modern CPUs (except Ice Lake where integer mov-elim is disabled), but it still takes up a ROB entry and front-end bandwidth.  As for a single instruction that checks that all selected bits are set, there isn't one in any modern ISA I know of.  There could be, and even BMI1/2 provides plenty of coding space for new opcodes.

Comment: You'd expect that a decent compiler would hoist the type checks out of a performance-critical inner loop, so I wouldn't really expect it to be all that beneficial to be able to perform this operation efficiently.  Moreover, since the alternative implementation is about two cycles of latency on a modern machine (0 for mov, 1 each for the simple ALU instructions), your savings are one clock cycle at best.  Compare with other bit operations that get their own instructions like `lzcnt`, where the equivalent software implementation is much much slower.